# Tests session does not end Rider

Tags: unit-testing, rider

I am using Rider on Mac version 2021.1.2 and what I noticed is that when I run tests  UniTest window for rider, there are times when even after tests are done executing, rider does not close session and the session is on forever.

- Clicking stop on the session does not respond
- The only way I found to get out of this situation is to close the Rider App.

I have been using Rider for a while and I have not seen this behavior before. Attaching a screen shot for the reference[[image]

Is it a Rider bug or if there is anything I can do to deal with this?

Comment: It looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-49332#focus=Comments-27-4354352.0-0. Have you had a message box "All unit tests are finished, but the test runner process is still running"?

Comment: I did not see any message box with error. Also, in the thread that you pointed, it sounds like they did take some action to fix it last year but I am seeing the issue still with the latest version. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: What options are selected on this page "Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Unit Testing | Test Runner" for "If the ... process does not exit after" settings?

Comment: Actually good point, it was set to "Keep waiting" and then I changed it to kill process and it does work. Thank you so much for your input.

Comment: Cool! Good to know you found the solution for the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mechanism in Rider/ReSharper which detects that the test runner or dotnet process runs indefinitely due to different reasons. It shows you the following dialog in such cases:

[image: Still running unit test runneer]

If you don't get this dialog, check the selected options for `If the ... process does not exit after` settings on the `Preferences/Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Unit Testing | Test Runner` page.

[image]